# informatica aggregator router and expression

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

would like to ask i have a scenario to translate this sql query to the informatica mapping:

```
select v.id, 

 case when v.type = 21 then nvl( 

    (SELECT nvl(SUM(nvl(amount,0)),0)  

    FROM view1 

    WHERE ctype IN (252,82) AND id = v.id AND id2 = v.id2

    GROUP BY id, id2) ,0) 

 else -1*nvl(

    (SELECT nvl(SUM(nvl(amt,0)),0)  

    FROM view2  

    WHERE vtype IN (252,82)  AND txn_id = v.txn_id  AND txn_id2 = 1  

    GROUP BY txn_id, txn_id2),0)  end AS amt1, 

case when v.type = 21 then nvl( 

    (SELECT nvl(SUM(nvl(amount,0)),0)  

    FROM view1  

    WHERE ctype IN (253,105) AND id = v.id  AND id2 = v.id2  

    GROUP BY id, id2),0)  

else -1*nvl(

    (SELECT nvl(SUM(nvl(amt,0)),0)  

    FROM view2  

    WHERE vtype IN (253,105)  AND txn_id = v.txn_id  AND txn_id2 = 1 

    GROUP BY txn_id, txn_id2),0)  

end AS amt2, 

case when v.type = 21 then  nvl( 

    (SELECT nvl(SUM(nvl(amount,0)),0)  

    FROM view1  

    WHERE ctype IN (251,75,136,135,149,164) AND id = v.id  AND id2 = v.id2  

    GROUP BY id, id2) ,0)  

else -1*nvl(

    (SELECT nvl(SUM(nvl(amt,0)),0)  

    FROM view2  

    WHERE vtype IN (251,75,136,135,149,164)  AND txn_id = v.txn_id  AND txn_id2 = 1  

    GROUP BY txn_id, txn_id2),0) 

end AS amt3,  

case when v.type = 21 then nvl( 

    (SELECT nvl(SUM(nvl(amount,0)),0)  

    FROM view1  

    WHERE ctype IN (6,101,148) AND id = v.id  AND id2 = v.id2  

    GROUP BY id, id2) ,0)  

else -1*nvl(

    (SELECT nvl(SUM(nvl(amt,0)),0)

    FROM view2  

    WHERE vtype IN (6,101,148) AND txn_id = v.txn_id  AND txn_id2 = 1 

    GROUP BY txn_id, txn_id2),0) end AS amt4    

from tblabc v, tblabc2 x

where v.status=2 and v.last_updated_datetime>sysdate

v.sid=x.sid (+)
```

How to code that in informatica?

First i use joiner from tblabc to view1 based on the id and id2 then

```
tblabc2 -> \
            joiner 1 ----------------------------------------------------?
tblabc ->  /   |
               |                  / -> aggregator for amt1

           joiner2 --> router <     -> aggregator for amt2

view1 -> /                        \ -> aggregator for amt3

                                    \-> aggregator for amt4

view2???
```

but how to join back from the aggregator for amt1,2,3,4 to joiner 1?

I'm not able to link it back, when i drag the arrow, it didnt show the link, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you're performing a self-join (as both pipelines originate from the same source). Before dragging ports to the joiner transformation, check the `Sorted input` property. And make sure both pipelines are indeed sorted on the keys - otherwise you'll get an execution error.